# Saving data with User defaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I am making a feature in my app that allows you to mute the music, i put a switch there so you can change it between on and off. However, the switch works fine in the app, when i close the vie controller and i pull it back up it will still show it how it was left, but when you close the app and open it back up the switch looks as if it off but it still plays the music.This is my code and i will attach a picture.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation




var bombSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer!
var Ghost = SKSpriteNode()

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var sw = false




@IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func switchpressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if mySwitch.isOn{
                defaults.set(true, forKey: "SwitchState")

        if bombSoundEffect != nil {
            bombSoundEffect.stop()
            bombSoundEffect = nil

        }

    }
    else{
        defaults.set(false, forKey: "SwitchState")

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "newmusic.wav", ofType:nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)


        do {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            bombSoundEffect = sound
            sound.numberOfLoops = -1
            sound.play()
        } catch {
            // couldn't load file :(
        }

    }


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if (defaults.object(forKey: "SwitchState") != nil) {
        mySwitch.isOn = defaults.bool(forKey: "SwitchState")


    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


}
```

and here is the picture
[image]
If you didn't understand what i said above please ask questions.

Comment: Are you playing the music in your app delegate or is all of your code in this view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand from your code, you are not checking the **User Defaults** properly. In your **viewDidLoad** you have to check the bool value of your **user defaults** is set to true or not.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    //check bool Value is set to true or not

    if defaults.bool(forKey: "SwitchState") == true {
        mySwitch.isOn = defaults.bool(forKey: "SwitchState")

    } else {
       print("false")

    }
}
```

Please check this code. Hopefully it will helps you.

Comment: I am not getting any errors but when I relaunch the app the music still plays but the switch is switched to mute

Comment: Have you try this code and can you show me what you are doing in app delegate.

Comment: I have nothing in my app delegate

Comment: And I am using your code in my ViewController.swift

Comment: Can you debug in viewDidLoad, When you relaunch the app, then in which condition it will goes, like If condition will execute or else will execute.

Comment: How would i debug my ViewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` you need to check for when you need to pause the music:

```
// Keep this part the same
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

if (defaults.object(forKey: "SwitchState") != nil) {
    mySwitch.isOn = defaults.bool(forKey: "SwitchState")
}

// Check to see if the switch is off, if so, stop the music
if !mySwitch.isOn {
    bombSoundEffect.stop()
    bombSoundEffect = nil
}
```

You can also take out the duplicate call to `super.viewDidLoad`.

***Note***: It really looks like there is more code in your view controller, because there isn't anything currently there that would be playing the music, so this solution may not work given that you haven't provided enough information.

Comment: I entered in exactly what you put and when i open up the viewController it mutes the music

Comment: @OrenEdrich Isn't this what you want?

Comment: No, I have the app play music in the background, and i this ViewController is the setting menu. So i have a switch in there that allows the user to mute the music. However, i am having a problem with saving if the switch is checked on our off

Comment: @OrenEdrich this question is super unclear. You don't include the code for when the music starts playing and you haven't explained when the music should stop/start.